# .getView.findViewById in fragment returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, getview

I know this has been addressed before but offered solutions don't seen to work. It would be greatly appreciated if you could take a look.

```
add = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();

        }

    });
```

The only error as far as I can tell is the getView() on the first line.

Comment: Post your whole fragment

Comment: If you call that before `onCreateView` or outside any method, then, yes, its null